# Displaying text after left mouse button was clicked

Tags: c++

I want to display text only after I clicked with left mouse button into the client area of the window. I have this code, but it doesn't work. When I click left mouse button nothing happens:

```
void Text(HDC hdc)
{
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    TCHAR display_msg[] = _T("Message in window");
    TextOut(hdc, RestartButtonWidth, 10, display_msg, _tcslen(display_msg));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    bool Clicked = false;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        if (Clicked == true) 
        {
            Text(hdc);
        }          

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        Clicked = true;
        break;
```

Why is the change of state of Clicked boolean not registered by WM_PAINT message?

Comment: Why should Clicked be true when you enter the CASE WM_PAINT block?

Comment: Please read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about scopes, and variable lifetime.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: static bool Clicked = false; will solve your problem for now, but I agree with @AlgirdasPreidžius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `WndProc` is called you create new variable `Clicked`.
So, on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` you set that local variable to `true` and that variable will be destroyed at the end of the scope. On the  `WM_PAINT` event you are checking state of newly created `Clicked` variable and state of that variable is `false`.

```
static bool Clicked = false;
```

is quick solution for your problem.

Comment: Do have any idea how to do this in OOP? Because when I set class variable to static then I get error: unresolved external symbol

Comment: That's another problem. You probably just declared your static member, you also need to define that member.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: bool ClassName::Clicked = false;              // definition (does not use 'static')